# Definition floating-point numbers in X86 Assembly - C Translation

Tags: c, assembly, x86, floating-point

Currently studying C. When I define, for example, a vector, such as:

```
float var1[2023] = {-53.3125}
```

What would the corresponding X86 Assembly translation look like? I'm looking for the exact portion of code where the variable is defined, where the ".type" and ".size" and alignment values are mentioned.

I've seen on the internet that when dealing with a floating-point number, the X86 Assembly conversion will simply be ".long". However, I'm not sure to what point that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy way to find out is to ask the compiler to show you:

```
// float.c
float var1[2023] = { -53.3125 };
```

then compile it:

```
$ gcc -S float.c
```

and then study the output:

```
        .file   "float.c"
        .globl  var1
        .data
        .align 32
        .type   var1, @object
        .size   var1, 8092
var1:
        .long   3260366848
        .zero   8088
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Note that this is just GCC's implementation; clang does it differently:

```
        .file   "float.c"
        .type   var1,@object            # @var1
        .data
        .globl  var1
        .align  16
var1:   
        .long   3260366848              # float -5.331250e+01
        .long   0                       # float 0.000000e+00
        .long   0                       # float 0.000000e+00
        // thousands of these
        .size   var1, 8092

        .ident  "clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)"
        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

**EDIT** - To answer the comment below, the use of `long` simply lays down a specific bit pattern that encodes the compiler's idea of floating point format.

The value `3260366848` is the same as hex `0xC2554000`, which is `11000010010101010100000000000000` in binary, and it's the binary value that the CPU cares about. If you care to, you can get out your IEEE floating point spec and decode this, there's the sign, that's the exponent, etc. but all the details of the floating point encoding were handled by the compiler, not the assembler.

I'm no kind of compiler expert, but decades ago I was tracking down a bug in a C compiler's floating point support, and though I don't remember the details, in the back of my mind it strike me as having the compiler do this would have been helpful by saving me from having to use a disassembler to find out what the bit pattern was actually encoded.

Surely others will weigh in here.

**EDIT2** Bits are bits, and this little C program (which relies on sizeof int and sizeof float being the same size), demonstrates this:

```c
// float2.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>


int main()
{
    float f = -53.3125;
    unsigned int i;

    printf("sizeof int = %lu\n", sizeof(i));
    printf("sizeof flt = %lu\n", sizeof(f));

    memcpy(&i, &f, sizeof i); // copy float bits into an int

    printf("float = %f\n", f);
    printf("i     = 0x%08x\n", i);
    printf("i     = %u\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Running it shows that bits are bits:

```
sizeof int = 4
sizeof flt = 4
float = -53.312500
i     = 0xc2554000
i     = 3260366848   <-- there ya go
```

This is just a display notion for 32 bits depending on how you look at them.

Now to answer the question of how would you determine 3260366848 on your own from the floating point value, you'd need to get out your IEEE standard and draw out all the bits manually (recommend strong coffee), then read those 32 bits as an integer.

Comment: Thank you! I had actually just done this. I failed to understand the value that comes after ".long", could you please explain?

Comment: I understand clang's approach too, but I still don't understand how any of the approaches arrive at 3260366848, I would've assumed the use of IEEE-754 floating-point representation. I apologize, I'm quite new at this but where does that value even come from?

Comment: 3260366848 is the binary encoding of the floating point value. You can look at any set of bits as anything: you say 65, I see the ASCII letter A.

Comment: What you edited in, regarding ".long" made perfect sense to me, obviously all the CPU cares about regarding nomenclature is how many bytes that actually represents, thank you. Regarding the binary encoding of the floating-point value, what I don't understand is how to determine this value. I am required to decode that value all by myself, for example, during a test, and I apologize if I seem ignorant or dumb, but I don't at all understand how I would even go about determining 3260366848. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Alright, so as I see it, 3260366848 is simply the 32 bits of binary code read as a regular binary number instead of being read as IEEE-754. Thanks!!

Comment: The GNU assembler can also compute the binary representation for you: just write `.float -53.312500`.  I don't know if there is a particular reason why the compilers prefer to do it themselves instead of leaving it to the assembler.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Likely because, at the time the decision was made to compute the representation in the compiler, the assembler either had no directive for recording floating-point values or it was not guaranteed to round correctly (or in the same way the compiler did). Or because doing it in the compiler would make it easier to put to arbitrary assemblers in the future, which might not have a floating-point data directive.

Comment: It doesn't seem out of the question that some compilers might have #pragmas for manipulating things like rounding modes, and this would be enforced on a concrete way by the compiler with a just-the-bits representation that would otherwise required passing on floating-point directives to the assembler?

Comment: @SteveFriedl: yeah, the compiler definitely wants to be able to output bit-exact FP values, including for FP values that result from constant-propagation and didn't appear in the source.  It's easier for everyone and removes a possible source of toolchain bugs if compilers do that with integer data directives instead of printing FP values back into decimal-float for the assembler to convert back into the nearest representable binary FP value.  Also presumably more performant, especially if the compiler is running on a machine with HW FP, or that doesn't support the same 80-bit `long double`...

Comment: @NateEldredge: see my previous comment.  Also just plain portability for cross-compilers if you compile GCC on a machine where host `double` differs from target `double`.  Or more likely, `long double` differs.

Comment: @Hasake: yes, when writing by hand you'd normally use `.float` and let the assembler convert `-53.312500` into an FP bit-pattern for you, instead of using `.long`.  But as discussed in comments above, compilers choose not to do that (because they already know the bit-pattern and/or other reasons).

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the reply. So technically it is more correct to write `.float` by hand, even though it is untrue? Because from what I'm seeing, all `.float` and `.long` do in this case is let the CPU know what size the variable is, given that either one will just be the binary codification of a value, correct?

Comment: @Hasake: What's "untrue"?  `.float` and `.long` are two different ways of emitting 4 bytes into the output file, nothing more nothing less.  If you want to let the assembler convert a decimal string into an IEEE binary32 bit pattern for you (presumably with round-to-nearest), go ahead and use `.float` for more readable source code.  Neither one is "more correct", only more human-friendly for future readers.  The CPU doesn't know anything about the size of the variable from this; you just have to use the right instructions (like `movss` instead of `movsd`) when you access this static storage.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for clarifying, what I meant by more correct was the fact that I always see `.long` where I'd assume `.float` to be, therefore I assumed `.long` to be more correct since it is what actually shows up. But I understand now. Again, thank you for clarifying.